# How do I declare an external char pointer?

Tags: c, syntax, variables, global-variables, external

File 1:

```
static char* const path; //GLOBAL

int main()
{
   path = FunctionReturningPath();
   UsePath()
}
```

File 2:

```
extern char* const path; //GLOBAL from file 1

UsePath() //function using global
{
   something = path;
}
```

(Pseudo)

Would like to use path in file 2.
I'm defining the global within main in file 1, is that bad practice using a global?

and doesn't compile:

```
Compile Error: error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _path
```

Any help is appreciated. Thank You.

Comment: One has `const`, and the other does not. Is this intended?

Comment: Now the `const`'s don't match. :) The first is a constant pointer to a mutable `char`, the second is a mutable pointer to a constant `char`.

Comment: And now if you simply omit `static`, it won't work either. You have to actively put `extern` and initialize it if you make the pointer itself const: Const makes it have internal linkage by default.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
static char* path; //GLOBAL
```

Wrong. making it static means it is local to the file, and cannot be exposed using extern. You want:

```
char* path; //GLOBAL
```

Answer (score 5):

The static keyword at the file scope means make the variable specific to that compilation unit.  Get rid of it.

Comment: (Nitpick, ignore if you (dis?)like) The proper term is "translation unit".

Comment: @KennyTM, thanks, I wonder where I (mis-)heard "compilation unit"?

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `static` keyword as it will make the symbol invisible to the linker.

In general, you should avoid global variables where you can. Instead, pass the variable as parameter where possible, or use a namespace (if you use C++). With global variables, you risk name clashes with external libraries, and the variable could be modified from anywhere.